# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql

I have two classes `DBConn` and `DBQueries`. `DBQueries` inherits after `DBConn`. When I'm going to display all users in users database, I see message:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
class DBConn /*extends Config*/ {
  public function dbConnection(){
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_login = 'root';
    $db_password = '';
    $db_name = "database";
    $conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name);
  }  
}
```

```
class DBQueries extends DBConn {
  function displayUsers(){
    $this->dbConnection();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo $row['password'];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are passing in `$query` which is your **sql string**, when you need to pass in `$result` which is your db result object.

```
class DBQueries extends DBConn {
    function displayUsers(){
        $this->dbConnection();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['password'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass in the result handle `$result` returned by `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass $result into the mysql_fetch_array function call as the first parameter, not $query.

```
class DBQueries extends DBConn {
  function displayUsers(){
    $this->dbConnection();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['password'];
    }
  }
}
```