# String given in mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, html, mysql, row, fetch

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");    
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("vinzq", $con);
session_start();
$confirmation = $_SESSION['confirm'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE confirmation = '$confirmation'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $arrival = $row['arrival'];
    $departure = $row['departure'];
    $adults = $row['adults'];
    $child = $row['child']; 
    $nroom = $row['no_room'];
    $result = $row['result'];
    $name = $row['firstname'];
    $last = $row['lastname'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $zip = $row['zip'];
    $country = $row['country'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $cnumber = $row['contact'];
    $stat= 'Active';
}
```

I have my codes here written in php. At the bottom after this code snippet, I have used html to display out the different variables. The values of the variables are correct, however the error that

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given,

still pops up even tho it's functional. The error seems to belong to the while statement line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901728/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-string-given)

Comment: I am not using oop, I'm embedding html in my php, for a website. @MHakvoort

Comment: try to print it `$confirmation` before your while loop

Comment: I have printed $confirmation out, and it is the same as the session variable being stored. @BeingSunny I think it is correct also, because the data it prints out like all the $arrival, $departure etc are all correct. I can get what I want, but it just shows that error over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line inside the `while` loop:

```
$result = $row['result'];
```

The first time through the loop, `$result` contains the result of `mysql_query()`. The second time, it contains the value of this field from the first row of results, so `mysql_fetch_array($result)` tries to use this string instead of the original query result.

Use different names for these two variables.

Comment: I don't have a line that reads: $result = $row['result']; are you talking about the data nested within the while loop? Like $arrival = $row['arrival'];? Sorry haven't been touching php for some time @Barmar

Comment: Yes, that's the line I'm talking about.

Comment: That was the error, duplicate variable name, because the original $result was within the while loop of the query $result execution... Thank you! @Barmar

Comment: Thank you for confirming the obvious.